# Progress Bar via threading VB.net is not updated

Tags: wpf, vb.net, progress-bar

I try to run a progress bar via multi threading while a time consuming codes are running but the progress bar is not being updated. Below is how I start the new thread :

```
Private Sub DevelopBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles SchExport.Click


    Dim excelWB As Excel.Workbook
    Dim ScheduleSht As Excel.Worksheet



    '**********************************Progress Bar*********************

    Dim newWindowThread As System.Threading.Thread = New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf test)
    newWindowThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA)
    newWindowThread.Start()
    '*********************************************************************
    Do something
```

and the test sub which is called by above codes is as follow:

```
Public Sub test()
    ' Create And show the Window
    Dim prog As BarProgress1 = New BarProgress1()
    prog.Show()
    '// Start the Dispatcher Processing
    prog.PB1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible
    prog.PB1.IsIndeterminate = False
    For n As Integer = 0 To 100
        Thread.Sleep(100)
        prog.Dispatcher.Invoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal, Sub()

                                                                                       prog.PB1.Value = 50
                                                                                       prog.TB.Text = n
                                                                                   End Sub)
        prog.PB1.IsIndeterminate = 50
    Next
    prog.Close()
End Sub
```

the codes are in WPF while prog is another window which contains progress bar and PB1 is the progress bar name.

Any help to resolve the problem is really appreciated.

Comment: Sure, this is all quite wrong.  The only thing that the SetApartmentState() call did is stopping WPF from telling you that you are doing it wrong.  It is however still very wrong.  The thread you created does not have a dispatcher, basic stuff like painting does not work.  Creating UI on another thread is a very bad idea and never necessary.  Keep the UI on the main thread, use a worker thread only to do non-UI related stuff.  And do beware that the Excel interfaces are single-threaded and enforce it too.  If you create them on the main thread then they always execute there.

Comment: @HansPassant I only want to have a progress bar and using threads is what I found out is recommended everywhere, after all, what is your suggestion then. What is the best way to do that.